# Strange logs in windows protected folders

Tags: windows-10

Hi I have windows 10 pro and I am facing a strange behavior. I was running out of disk space and after research I found that I had more than 6 million HTM files in two folders:

1. C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE
2. C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE

Example of a log files look like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=unicode-1-1-utf-8"><!-- saved from url=(0015)assemblybinder: --><html><pre>
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (11/30/2017 @ 8:04:32 AM) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.FWDEV\MSSQL\Binn\Polybase\mpdwsvc.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.MessageTypes, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL13.FWDEV/MSSQL/Binn/Polybase/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : DMS, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.FWDEV\MSSQL\Binn\Polybase\Dms.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file:
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.MessageTypes, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL13.FWDEV/MSSQL/Binn/Polybase/Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.MessageTypes.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.FWDEV\MSSQL\Binn\Polybase\Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.MessageTypes.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.MessageTypes, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.FWDEV\MSSQL\Binn\Polybase\Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.MessageTypes.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

I've managed to remove the files from both folder by using command line bash for windows with administrator privileges, by running command:

find . -name "*.HTM" -delete

I both of the mentioned folders. And I happily got back about 29 GB of space after some time. So I have the work around to use when I have to clean disk. But I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Right now everything is working fine and I don't see any problems. However I am curious:

1. What are these logs?
2. What causes storing them in such a strange place?
3. Can I somehow turn it off, I don't want to run this clean up every month
4. Am I doing something dangerous by manually deleting them?

Answer (score 1):

You can try turning off Fusion (.NET) logs:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion

ForceLog set value to 0
LogFailures set value to 0
LogResourceBinds set value to 0
EnableLog set value to 0

Or you can try changing log path to another location:

Add new String value called LogPath and set value to folder for logs (e.g. C:\FusionLog)

Or,
If you have the Windows SDK installed on your machine, you can use the "Fusion Log Viewer"...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately because I changed my machine few months ago I can't check if it solves the problem, cause it does not appear on my fresh installation of windows. But really, thanks for the effort! Hope somebody finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

These folders are home of the Internet Explorer cache. You can delete all Temporary Internet Files in "Options".

You ´re not breaking anything by manually deleting them.

You can also set it up any way you like it. Read this: https://www.howtogeek.com/127565/how-to-modify-caching-behavior-in-internet-explorer-10/

Comment: Well that's interesting but why that happens since I am not using Internet Explorer or Edge. And why this files grow so rapidly. Have in mind that I deleted about 29 GB. And I've tried deleting these files in Internet Explorer options but it didn't work. But anyway thanks for the hint.

Comment: Don´t know. Maybe you´re using an application that uses IE?